# How To Add New Document To Firestore Database Using Rest API Javascript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create a new document in my firestore database using the REST API with javascript.

I have looked at the documentation for examples but I don't see any when it comes to using the Rest Api in Javascript.

I have constructed it in Postman and it works ok but I just cannot figure it out how to wire this upto a button click event in javascript.

Does anyone have a working example I can learn from please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example with fetch, based on the Firestore REST API [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents/createDocument).

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />

    <script>
      function saveDoc() {
   
        // We first build the Document object
        // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases.documents#Document

        const firebaseDocObj = {
          fields: {
            name: {
              stringValue: 'Magritte',
            },
            country: {
              stringValue: 'Belgium',
            },
          },
        };

        fetch(
          'https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<your-project-id>/databases/(default)/documents/test-collection',
          {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(firebaseDocObj),
          }
        )
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
            return response.json();
          })
          .then((data) => {
            alert('Doc created');
            console.log('success', data);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(error));
            console.log('failed', error);
          });
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <input
      id="clickMe"
      type="button"
      value="Create a doc"
      onclick="saveDoc();"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```